# Animated Gift Unwrapping

Tags: mesh, uv

I've been struggling for some time to make a christmas animation with an unwrapping gift ribbon, but I cannot get it to work.

I am trying to achieve the effect that is showcased in the beginning of this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gkIvw4GtXNw

Has anyone done something like this in Blender?

Comment: Looking at the reference version frame-by-frame.. it's quite a cheat. It may help to have a close look at that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try it this way: Create a curve, hook its vertices to some empties, make the ribbon mesh follow the curve with a *Curve* modifier, parent the empties and the ribbon to the curve, parent the curve to a big empty:

[image]

Create some keyframes on the empties to unfold the curve:

[image]

Duplicate all the objects, rotate and move, result (here I use the exact same animation for the 4 tips but of course it would be better to use a different one):

[image]

File: [image]

Comment: Thank you very much! You're great, it will surely work this way.

Comment: Hey! I have tried your method, I got the idea and everything but I cannot get the fold like you did, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Maybe if you can help me with the project or more screenshots on how you keyframed everything it will help, thank you a lot and sorry for the misundestanding! :D

Comment: Here is my file, maybe it will help, or please share yours: https://blend-exchange.com/b/DdqGNBQ1

Comment: Thank you so much! It will surely help a lot, I will post here the final file I will do maybe it will help other people too! :D